# Determine the coordinates of a segment

Tags: atan2

How can I use `atan2` to determine the coordinates where a segment ends, knowing the coordinates where it starts (`x, y`), the angle of the segment and the length of the segment?

Can you tell me a solution it doesn't have to be only with atan2...

Answer (score 0):

You have a right angled triangle and you can assume that the point A is at (x,y), this is much easier to explain with the use of some diagrams:

[image: right angled triangle]

Now we know what the value for c is already because this is the length of the segment and we want to know the values for a and b because the final point is at `(x+b, y+a)`

From trigonometry we know what the relations between the angles and the ratios of the sides are
[image: tight angle triangle angles]

`sin(theta) = opposite/hypotenuse` and `cos(theta) = adjacent/hypotenuse`

Substituting in the values we know we get:

```
sin(theta) = opposite/c
c = opposite * sin(theta)
```

and

```
cos(theta) = adjacent/b
b = adjacent * cos(theta)
```

We know that the end point is at `(x+b, y+a)` which given the values for the edges we found is `(x+adjacent * cos(theta), y+opposite * sin(theta))`